# Visual C++ create a dynamic data breakpoint

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'd like to create a data breakpoint specifically for Visual C++ so when a variable at pointer x is modified or read, my program can detect this and see what instruction accessed the variable. I know this can be done using Visual Studios features, however, I'd like to detect variable change/read by an instruction dynamically inside my code.

Basically, I want to be able to get what instruction accessed my data at pointer x using C++ code. If you need clarification, feel free to comment below!

Comment: Usually, you should avoid public data anyway... and when you have a function, it is very easy to know when it is called and by referring to some good patterns' book, you should be able to implement some notification mechanism.

Comment: Cheat Engine does that but it's source is not C++ (at least the part where it does data breakpoints by itself)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a simple task. Data access breakpoints are supported by the hardware.  To access those in Windows you need to use the [Debugger Programming Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt809566(v=vs.85).aspx).

You're probably better off using access control, getters, and setters to track that.

Comment: Cheat Engine does that but it's source is not C++ (at least the part where it does data breakpoints by itself)